# AltGr+S in TeXstudio tries to save file

Tags: texstudio, keyboard

Recently (2 days ago) I downloaded TeXstudio along with all packages I need. Today I also worked out how to make polish characters work (like `ą`, `ę`, `ł`), but whenever I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> (which should result with `ś` on polish keyboard) TeXstudio opens save file window, so I am unable to input that character properly. I can't see any <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut in settings either.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Some more details would be useful, for example which is your operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some keyboard layouts <kbd>AltGr</kbd> works like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Control_.2B_Alt_as_a_substitute

This is the shortcut for `Save As`. You can deactivate it in `Options -> Shortcuts`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you need to create file `shortcuts.ini` in configuration folder. In my case: `C:\MikTex portable\TeXworks\0.4\configuration`.

In created file write:

```
actionSave_As =
actionSave_All =
```

or

```
actionSave_As = ctrl+shift+s
actionSave_All =
```

After editor restart it should resolve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).